# href não funciona de forma alguma

Tags: html

Meu href não funciona de forma alguma:

```
 <div class="container-contact1-form-btn">
            <a href="FormularioDeBusca.html">
                <button class="contact1-form-btn">Formulario de Busca</button>
            </a>
 </div>
```

No caso a forma que estou referenciando está errada.

Comment: Existem, pelo menos, 10 `href` no seu codigo. O que, **exatamente**, você está tentando fazer e qual é o problema? Recomendo que faça o [tour] para entender o básico do funcionamento do site e leia o guia de [ask] para ver como melhorar sua pergunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Utilize dessa forma

```
<div class="container-contact1-form-btn">
            <a href="FormularioDeBusca.html" class="contact1-form-btn">Formulario de Busca</a>
        </div>
```